# How can show a value selected into a text field?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to show the value from the select box selected into a text field

```
<%= select_tag "customer_id", options_for_select(@customers.collect {|t| [t.correct_name,t.id]},params[:customer_id].to_i) %>

<%= f.text_field :customer,:value => @customer.id %>
```

I tried [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/69UAT/) but is just for inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your **`text_field`** to like this

```
<%= f.text_field :customer,:id => "customer",:value => "" %>
```

And have a try with this

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $value = $('#customer');
    $('select[name="customer_id"]').change(function(){
        $value.val($(this).val())
    }).triggerHandler('change')
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pavan28/TZd5y/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#customer_id").on("change", function() {
  $(this).parent().find("input").val($(this).val());
});
```